# OpenERP - How to modify 'kanban' element via inheritance?

Tags: xml, inheritance, view, odoo

I tried to modify kanban element in view adding more attributes to it, but it gives me this error:

```
2014-01-02 14:22:23,653 23604 ERROR test2 openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_ui_view: <string>:1:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_NOELEM: Expecting an element , got nothing
```

My view:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads_inherit">
        <field name="name">CRM - Leads Kanban Inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <kanban default_group_by="stage_id" position="replace">
                <kanban default_group_by="stage_id" edit="false" quick_create="false"/>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I solved this by just simply copying whole view defined in original module and changing it, but I think there should be much better solution than that. How could I modify 'root' element  inside view (as 'kanban' element is root for for all fields, buttons etc.)

P.S. I posted this question here too http://help.openerp.com/question/40598/how-to-modify-kanban-element-via-inheritance/ but as there is much smaller community, so I'm asking here as there is better change that someone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is actually wrong. Here you are using `position="replace"` which will replace the whole thing that come under `<kanban>... </kanban>`. As you just need to add new attributes to this kanban, you can use `position="attributes"`. For example

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads_inherit">
    <field name="name">CRM - Leads Kanban Inherit</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban default_group_by="stage_id" position="attributes">
            <attribute name='edit'>false</attribute>
            <attribute name='quick_create'>false</attribute>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could use position for attributes.